# codeigniter view data for each month based on location and date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table like this below :

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlokW.jpg)

and mysql structure like this :

```
+--------+-------------------+---------+-------+----------+
| id_log | nama_kec          | tanggal | bulan |kadar_ispu|
+--------+-------------------+---------+-------+----------+
|  1001  | Bengkalis         |    1    |   12  |   100    |
|  1002  | Bengkalis         |    5    |   12  |   0      |
|  1003  | Bandar Sei Kijang |    1    |   12  |   10     |
|  1004  | Bandar Petalangan |    1    |   12  |   0      |
+--------+-------------------+---------+-------+----------+
```

edit :

here's my controller to call all those data

```
public function tampil($id_bulan='')
{  
//get $id_bulan  
$ambil_bulan = $this->db->select('nama_bulan,id_bulan')
                        ->get('bpbd_bpbd_bulan')->result();  
$output['ambil_bulan'] = $ambil_bulan;  

//get data nama_kec,tanggal, bulan, kadar_ispu
$data = $this->db->select('a.id_log,a.nama_kec,a.tanggal,a.bulan,a.kadar_ispu,b.nama,c.nama_bulan')
                     ->join('bpbd_bpbd_kecamatan as b','b.id_kec = a.nama_kec')
                     ->join('bpbd_bpbd_bulan as c','c.id_bulan = a.bulan')
                     ->where('a.bulan',$id_bulan)
                     ->get('bpbd_bpbd_log_ispu as a')->result_array();  

$output['id_bulan'] = $id_bulan;  
$output['bulan_ganjil'] =$bulan_ganjil;  
$output['data'] = $data;  

//show the view  
$this->view($this->cms_module_path().'/log_ispu',$output,$this->n('log_ispu'));  
}  

</code>
```

We can see from image above that Wilayah("Bengkalis") data below ->'-' which came from 5 Desember should be shown at the same row as Wilayah("Bengkalis") at the top since its from the same month which is Desember but different date. any advice on how to do this?

Comment: database requets should happen in model files

Comment: i am using grocery_crud here to make database request in the same page as controller

Comment: this is the example of what i want to do http://imgur.com/jt79bWg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very big task can't be explain all the items and codes. It may help you how to implement this,

Here is a out sketch of how to achieve this,

-> First fetch all the name results along with primaryId

-> Second fetch all the date and name results along with primaryId

Then use this date loop

```
//lets assume this contains the name results with primaryId
$aNameResult;

$aData = array();

$iMonthDays = 30;

foreach($aNameResult as $aRow) {
   //lets assume this contains the date based results with primaryid
   $aDateResult; //$aRow['primaryId']

   //first fill the available date details
   foreach($aDateResult as $aDateRow){
      //assign records for your daye
      $aData[date('j', strtotime($aDateRow['date']))] = array();//anything you want assign it to the day
   }

   //fill all the remaining dates
   for($i=1; $1<=$iMonthDays; $i++) {
     if(!array_key_exists($i, $aData)) {
        $aData[$i] = array();//assign anything you want
     }
   }

  print_r($aData);
  die();//print the per name 30 days record details
}
```

Comment: how do i iterate through odd and even months? i want to get the paramater of odd or even months based on the same database

Comment: you can find the odd and even month using modular operator `($month%2==0)?'EvenMonth':'OddMonth'`